# Liferay best practice in how to make view model/layer and how to display 2 table records using liferay-search-container

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

What is the best practice to implement the view layer in Liferay?
And how do I show records from two tables using the "liferay-search container-row"?

I will explain next what I have done in my project so you have a proper view of my question and what I'm talking about.

I used the **service builder** and I got the *PERSISTENCE* and the *SERVICE* layer

I used the **service.xml** and created my 2 entities.

Then, in the xxxLocalServiceImpl I created the necessary methods for the update, add, delete...

And then for the **presentation** layer(view) I added a new liferay module using the mvc-portlet template called xxx-WEB (So now I have the xxx-API, xxx-SERVICE and XXX-WEB).

I did all that, so I have my **three layers** right? (The Model, Controller and View).

So, then I had an issue showing **records from the two tables in just one** 
When I say this, I'm referring *showing the 2 table data using the Liferay-search-container*, Since In the `className` as shown below I'm already defining a Model, and I can't define the other model to show the data from two tables in the search container. example:
`<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.liferay.training.xxx.model.xxx" keyProperty="xxx" modelVar="xxx">`

Since I can only use one **Model** to get the table data, I could not show the data from the other table.

*So what I did was exposing the other entity(Author) to the other one(Music).*

I went to the **MusicImpl class** an *created a property of Author type, and the getter and setters methods.*

Then in the **MusicLocalServiceImpl** in the **addMusicAndAuthor method** *I setted the author for that music* example: music.setAuthor(author).

After that, for being able to show all the data in my JSP i needed to *override* the *getter of the MovieLocalService*, the **getMusics(int start, int end)**.

What I did in my *override* was *fetching all the movies*, and for each movie I *setted the Author*

code:

```
@Override
public List<Music> getMusics(int startPos, int endPost) {
    List<Music> musics = super.getMusics(startPos, endPost);

    if ((musics != null && (!musics.isEmpty()))) {
        Author author;

        for (Music music: musics) {
            try {
                author = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthorByMusicId(author.getMusicId());
                music.setAuthor(author);
            } catch (NoSuchAuthorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return musics;
}
```

*And then in my JSP I was able to show de data from the two tables doing the following:*

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <%
        int totalMusics = MusicLocalServiceUtil.getMusicsCount();
        results = MusicLocalServiceUtil.getMusics(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd());
        searchContainer.setTotal(totalMusics);
        searchContainer.setResults(results);
    %>
</liferay-ui:search-container-results>

<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.liferay.training.musics.model.Music"
    keyProperty="musicId" modelVar="currentMusic">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Name" property="musicName"/>

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="author" value="<%=currentMusic.getAuthor().getAuthorName() %>"/>

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp align="center" path="/button.jsp"/>
</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

*that way I could show in a table the records from 2 tables.*

But what I want to know, is if *is there another way to do this*, because a friend told me that a could do a *viewmodel* and a *view layer*, he told me to create a package for the model view, I suppose classes named **MusicViewModel** and **AuthorViewModel** with *getters and setters* and with that I would **not need to override**, and I should not do that override.

but that doesn't make much sense for me since I already have a view layer and liferay already made that model for me in the API right? or am I missing something? 
is there another way to show the data from the two tables without that override? does it make any sense to do what my friend told me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you refactor your question, so it would be less wordy, more structured and use more highlights from Markdown? It is hard even to refactor your question, not saying to go through the question and understand essential part.

Comment: Just finished editing, fixed some typos and it's better structured, but for the less wordy i can't do less than that, because I'm explained how I got to a problem, how I solved it, and questioning if thats ok or not, so the community can understand and give me some explanation.